# When do jQuery submit functions link themselves to HTML forms?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have several forms in my HTML page whose submission is facilitated by jQuery functions. They   work well.  However, I am having issues with forms that are dynamically created. Rather than being submitted via jQuery, they are being posted to the current HTML page.

For instance, I have a table that is dynamically created with PHP. That table can be updated as it is enclosed in a form.

Here's the code for generating the table:

```
//Display table
            echo "<form id=\"UpdateUsers\" method=\"post\">";
            echo "<table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User Id </th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Current Publisher</th>
                    <th>User Priveleges</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>";

                foreach($publishers as $row)
                    foreach($row as $col)
                    {
                        $i++;

                        switch ($i) { 
                            case 4: //Is it a current publisher?
                                if($col == 0) 
                                    echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"current\" name=\"UserState[$row[0]]\" value=\"1\" ></td>\n";
                                else
                                    echo "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"current\" name=\"UserState[$row[0]]\" value=\"1\" checked> </td>\n";
                                break;

                            case 5: //Do they have user priveleges?
                                if($col == 0)
                                    echo "<td>No</td>\n";
                                else
                                    echo "<td>Yes</td>\n";
                                echo "</tr><tr>"; //start a new row
                                $i=0; //reset counter
                                break;

                            default:
                                echo "<td>$col</td>\n";     
                        }
                    }
                echo "</tr></tbody></table>";   
                echo "<button type=\"submit\">Update</ button>";
                echo "</form>";
        }
```

The form id is clearly `UpdateUsers`.

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#UpdateUsers').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#results').contents().remove();

    //Make sure all checkboxes are submitted
    var cb = this.getElementsByTagName('input'); //Get the inputs
    for(var i=0;i<cb.length;i++){ 
        if(cb[i].type=='checkbox' && !cb[i].checked)  // if this is an unchecked checkbox   
        {
            cb[i].value = 0; // set the value to "off"
            cb[i].checked = true; // make sure it submits
        }
    }

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $("input").prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.post('VRC_PublishersProcess.php', formData, resultsMessage);
    request.fail(function() { 
        $('#results').append("<span id=\"reply\">Updating failed for an unknown reason. Please try again in a few minutes.</ span>");           
        $("input").prop("disabled", false); });


    function resultsMessage(data) {
        $('#results').append(data);
        $("input").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
});
```

This jQuery function has been used in the past, so it should be valid and functioning code; I doubt it is the source of the problem.

My suspicion is that as the browser loads it is processing and "linking" the jQuery and HTML code. Once a new form dynamically shows up, the browser doesn't know that there is a jQuery function that handles the submission request.

If that is really the case, how can I modify my current code to behave in the proper manner. That is, allow jQuery to handle the post request.

Any input is appreciated.

This is what I mean by dynamically created:

(1) User makes request on current HTML page:

```
   <div id="pub1">
            <a href="#" class="drop" id="one">Other</a>
            <div id="displayselect">
                <form id="select1" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="All" value="1" />
                    <input type="submit" name="All" value="All Publishers" />
                </form>
                <form id="select2" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Current" value="1" />
                    <input type="submit" name="Current" value="Current Publishers" />
                </form>
                <form id="select3" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Users" value="1" />
                    <input type="submit" name="Users" value="User Priveleges" />
                </form>
           </div>
        </div>
```

(2) Request is handled by jQuery - it sends the post request to a php page, which will then generate the table (this is one of three identical jQuery functions):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#select3').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#results').contents().remove();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $("input").prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.post('VRC_PublishersProcess.php', formData, resultsMessage);
    request.fail(function() { 
        $('#results').append("<span id=\"reply\">Your search failed for an unknown reason. Please try again in a few minutes.</ span>");            
        $("input").prop("disabled", false); });


    function resultsMessage(data) {
        $('#results').append(data);
        $("input").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
});
```

(3) Note that the above jQuery function handles server feedback. It displays that feedback in the div with the id of `results`.

Comment: When you say that the form is being dynamically created, do you mean by an AJAX function? After the form is created, and you do a `view source`, is the JavaScript on the active page?

Comment: @mlagma are you using the jQuery Form plugin? Have you tried inspecting your page to ensure the right jQuery plugins are loading with the page? Your best bet may be to step through your code and see if the element is available when the submit function is being assigned.

Comment: @DevlshOne See the recent edition to my post. In addition, all of my JavaScript is linked to the page - it is in an external file. And yes, it is present.

Comment: @ermagana I'm not using a jQuery Form plugin. In terms of jQuery source files, I am using jquery.min.js and jquery.js. In any case, I have many more jQuery functions of similar form that work properly. The only issues I am having are with dynamically generated forms - meaning after initial page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('submit','#UpdateUsers',function (e) { // delegated event with fixed els!
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#results').contents().remove();

    //Make sure all checkboxes are submitted
    var cb = this.getElementsByTagName('input'); //Get the inputs
    for(var i=0;i<cb.length;i++){ 
        if(cb[i].type=='checkbox' && !cb[i].checked)  // if this is an unchecked checkbox   
        {
            cb[i].value = 0; // set the value to "off"
            cb[i].checked = true; // make sure it submits
        }
    }

    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $("input").prop("disabled", true);
    request = $.post('VRC_PublishersProcess.php', formData, resultsMessage);
    request.fail(function() { 
        $('#results').append("<span id=\"reply\">Updating failed for an unknown reason. Please try again in a few minutes.</ span>");           
        $("input").prop("disabled", false); });


    function resultsMessage(data) {
        $('#results').append(data);
        $("input").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
});
```

It looks like you need to delegate the event since the form is being created dynamically. Try it with the `.on('submit', function(e)` and see if it works.

Comment: That's interesting. I was thinking of putting an `onSubmit` event handler in the form itself. My concern is that the new form and already processed JavaScript won't "link" to each other. By the way, it would be the first jQuery function. The one you are using is an example I gave of a jQuery function that already works.

Comment: I changed my answer to reflect the first script.

Comment: Well, I just tried that. It didn't work. It doesn't even look like the script was executed. I used chrome's inspect element, and no errors were thrown either. I'm stumped.

Comment: Could you copy and paste the results of a `view-source` into a jsFiddle where the table is already created based on the user input?

Comment: Oh shoot... I forgot to change the element tags in the `.on()`. Make the changes as shown and try it again.

Comment: I'm having trouble copying the table. View page source is showing an empty results div - even though I see a table. I only see a table in inspect elements.

Comment: Ah, my noticing refresh post would have been helpful! And it works perfectly! Thank you. What is the fundamental difference between `.submit` and `.on`? It is delegating the event, obviously, but why doesn't `.submit` do the same?

Comment: the `.on()` binds the event handler to any existing or FUTURE instances of an element where `.submit()` only binds to existing elements.  http://api.jquery.com/on/